# ¿como pongo los errores de un validation_errors() en un toast de materialize?

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, codeigniter, materialize

estoy utilizando el framework codeigniter y estoy validando un formulario con el helper que viene por defecto en codeigniter.
Estoy usando materialize como framework de diseño y quiero imprimir los errores que me devuelve el helper en un toast de materialize y no sale el toast.

A continuación les dejo mi js

```js
//ERRORES DE FORMULARIO
  var toastHTML = '<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>';
  M.toast({html: toastHTML});
```

y me fije en el view-souce y si me imprime el mensaje como deberia.

```js
//ERRORES DE FORMULARIO
  var toastHTML = '<p>El campo Nombre es obligatorio.</p>
';
  M.toast({html: toastHTML});
```

Answer (score 0):

YA LO SOLUCIONE
Dejo la pregunta por si a alguien le sirve.
lo que pasaba es que la función validation_errors() devuelve una lista y genera un problema, la solucion fue mostrar lo errores de cada campo individual.
aca les dejo el codigo.

```js
  var toastHTML = '<?php echo form_error('nombre')?>';
  M.toast({html: toastHTML});
```